# What's the syntax for this kind of declaration in MASM32?

Tags: syntax, assembly, masm32

```
szCaption db 'System Information', 0
```

I now understand such declarations:

```
var_name type default_value
```

Which has 3 parts. But what's the syntax for the declarations above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, a better description is:

```
var_name type comma-separated list of values
```

In your example, each character in the string is a byte. And so is the trailing zero. MASM allows either characters or numbers.

Your example forms a null-terminated string.

Comment: Is this valid? `total int 1,2,3` ?

Comment: @assem: `int` signifies the Interrupt instructions, not a data type. However, you can use `DW`, `DD`, etc. and then `1,2,3` would be allowed.

Answer (score 0):

db actually stands for 'define bytes' and can accept as arguments quoted strings (single or double quotes) and numbers, separated by commas.